# Removing .php file extension from the end of a url.

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-extension

I am trying to achieve something very simple on my web server. I want urls that end in .php to end with / for example www.example.net/something.php to be www.example.net/something or www.example.net/folder/subfolder/something.php to be www.example.net/folder/subfolder/something. Additionally I don't mind if I have www.example.net/folder/something.php?something=whatever/. I am only concerned with removing the last .php in the url. I have used this code amongst many others.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

However this only works for some of my pages. For example it does not work on my www.example.com/folder/contactus.php page. Instead I get my 404 page. But it works on www.example/folder/faq.php perfectly.
Additionally I make some file_get_contents() php request within various parts of my code. Is there any way to tailor these rules so internal requests (my php functions) are not affected.  Basically I only want the browser to display the url without the .php end without affecting my other php functions that are held in .php files. For further clarification of my intentions: I use a string processing functions to extract particular lines of text from a php file based on variables I have set up. But with the current rewrite rules the php file cannot be found because the extension has been removed from the filename (im guessing.

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($filename);
```

I'm currently using a linux server on a shared godaddy host account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to apply the php check to both rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f 
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

Additionally, the -f check needs to be made without the trailing slash

Comment: It still behaves weird. Firstly the internal php scripts and function calls are left intact. That is great. However it still does this 
`http://www.sitename.net/folder/something.php to http://www.sitename.net/folder/something.php`
and in on other files in the same directory
`http: //www.sitename.net/folder/something.php to http://www.sitename.net/folder/something/` 
Strangely enough one of the pages does this `http://www.sitename.net/var/chroot/home/content/37/9179448/html/control/something` which leads to my 404 page. Your exact code above is why I used.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked as desired, though one of my pages used get request which failed. I just changed it to a post request and all was well.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^.\ ]+\.)+php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.sitename.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*index/?$ http://www.sitename.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.sitename.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^([^.]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

One small problem still remains. Some pages the trailing slash is appended and others they are not. Any clues on forcing the trailing slash?

Comment: I have one major problem. All my POST form submissions returns the 404 page. For some reason I can't resolve post form submissions.